# DRF JSON Token Authentication

Tags: authentication, django-rest-framework, token, jwt, django-rest-auth

I have to implement following features with RESTAPI:

- register user
- authorize user and get token
- get user data by token
- create user's post via token (Title, Body)
- get user's posts via token
- get all posts via token
- user profile has to be customized - main fields are email/password

models.py:

http://pastebin.com/8V7CzrVi

serializers.py:

http://pastebin.com/W7Dn8Msn

views.py:

http://pastebin.com/L5ijkd5F

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include('app.urls')),
]
```

app.urls:

```
from .views import Register, UserList, UserDetail, PostList, PostDetail
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/$', UserList.as_view(), name='user-list'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', UserDetail.as_view(), name='user-detail'),
    url(r'^posts/$', PostList.as_view(), name='post-list'),
    url(r'^posts/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    url(r'^login/', obtain_jwt_token),
    url(r'^register/$', Register.as_view()),

]
```

First question - please, review the code and tell, am I right in my realization? (THANKS A LOT for any corrections, hints and explanations)

Second one - how can I perform creating the post or viewing of post's list without any client code?

I mean following:

- I am going into browserable API at api/register, enter email and password, hit post and get object of user
- then I am going at api/login, enter email and password of the user just registered, hit post and get object with token - {'token': 'sometoken'}
- then I am trying to create the post or get post's list, using httpie. In the console I enter -

http POST 127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts "Authorization: Token sometoken"

or

http GET 127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts "Authorization: Token sometoken"

and get:

```
HTTP/1.0 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 03 Sep 2016 10:22:33 GMT
Location: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.11
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

I do not understand how I can check every endpoint with using token.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I think you'll probably get all of this for free from django-rest-auth: https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth

Comment: sorry..but I really have no time to figure other libraries out.. thanks for helping with existing code!